# GWT app starting from IntelliJIDEA needs 2. Runs (Debug or Run = same ballon notice)

Tags: intellij-idea, gwt

I have some strange behaviour, 1. time if I hit debug from IntelliJIDEA, I notice the following, message and the project is not starting. (3 ballons on the right side)

[image]

If i hit a 2. time DEBUG in IntelliJIDEA, all is starting up fine.

Maybe someone, had similar problems and could help. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug. Please upvote it at JetBrains:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283472